# Spring boot Interceptor dont show @ControllerAdvice errorhandler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interceptor

Implemetation: Im trying to implementin project with `Interceptor` but the Error handling in showing only in `Terminal` which is good but i need also to show in restapi in postman and its showing empty.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


public class WebInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception    {
        logger.error("WebInterceptor preHandle is now logged");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        logger.error("WebInterceptor posthandle is now logged");
        HandlerInterceptor.super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {
        logger.error("WebInterceptor afterCompletion is now logged");
        HandlerInterceptor.super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
    }
    
    


    
    
    
    

}
```

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(new WebInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/cart/**").order(1);
        registry.addInterceptor(new WebInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/product/**").order(2);
    }
    
    
    
    

}
```

```
import com.kongapigateway.KongAPIgateway.ModelException.DATE_FORMAT_ERROR;
import com.kongapigateway.KongAPIgateway.ModelException.ProductExecption;
import com.kongapigateway.KongAPIgateway.ModelException.ProductIDnotFound;
import com.kongapigateway.KongAPIgateway.ModelException.ProductValueNotNull;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class WEbAspectExceptionConfig {
    
     private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WEbAspectExceptionConfig.class);

        @ExceptionHandler(ProductValueNotNull.class)
        @ResponseStatus
        public void handle(ProductValueNotNull e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        @ExceptionHandler(DATE_FORMAT_ERROR.class)
        @ResponseStatus
        public void handle2(DATE_FORMAT_ERROR e) {
               logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        @ExceptionHandler(ProductExecption.class)
        @ResponseStatus
        public void handle2(ProductExecption e) {
               logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        @ExceptionHandler(ProductIDnotFound.class)
        @ResponseStatus
        public void handle2(ProductIDnotFound e) {
               logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        

}
```

Terminal Output:
This is the error handling message: `Please input all field`

```
kongapigateway    | 2022-06-07 11:21:33.149  INFO 1 --- [nio-8095-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
kongapigateway    | 2022-06-07 11:21:33.161 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8095-exec-1] c.k.K.Interceptor.WebInterceptor         : WebInterceptor preHandle is now logged
kongapigateway    | 2022-06-07 11:21:33.277 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8095-exec-1] c.k.K.AOP.WEbAspectExceptionConfig       : Please input all field
kongapigateway    | 2022-06-07 11:21:33.277 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8095-exec-1] c.k.K.Interceptor.WebInterceptor         : WebInterceptor afterCompletion is now logged
```

Postman api error handler is Empty

[Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe5WI.png)

Comment: Is your rest api controller extending the `WEbAspectExceptionConfig` class?

Comment: @derstauner no, but i will test it

Comment: @derstauner still empty

Comment: What has your interceptor to do with this? If you want to send a response, do that from your `@ControllerAdvice` method, that now only logs to the logger (and probably the console).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly `disregard` this Post Question.
I used Spring AOP @Around for customize exception.

Thank you.